# Solr: find documents that contain a field value that a query string starts or ends with

Tags: solr

I want to find documents that contain a field value that a query string starts or ends with -- a "backwards query" (or whatever it's called).

Say I have a document with the following field value:

```
allowed_hosts: *.example.org
```

I want a query for `host1.example.org` to match this.

It would be nice to support a wildcard character (stored in the documents), but not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Cane be done using `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`
For prefix match

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

using the EdgeNGramFilter. Grams(tokens) are created for any length between 3 and 15,

For suffix match

changing `side` parameter value to `back` will  work for solr version <=4.3

from solr4.3+ We have to combine it with ReverseStringFilter

```
<filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

For More details check this out [here](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/03/prefix-and-suffix-matches-in-solr.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work, as it will match any of the grams. For example, a query for "123.123.123.123" will match a document containing "123.4."